# Firebase Quickstart Analytics Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :internal:lintchecks

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build.gradle

I imported the firebase quickstart analytics for android as an Android Studio project but when I try to sync it I got these errors :

[image]

I already tried a lot of advises from other topics (unckecked offline mode etc...) but no one solved the issue.

Here is my build.gradle (app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner                                                                                                                                           '       android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}

dependencies {
implementation project(":internal:lintchecks")
implementation project(":internal:chooser")
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71"

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is a screenshot of the console where we can see the "internal" dependency folder, but there is nothing inside..

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5jeX.png)

Comment: There is also spaces in: `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:3.0.2` which I didn't add it in my answer since I thought it might be a pasting typo.

Comment: I am also having this error while trying the quickstart android example. any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you imported only **analytics** folder from the entire Firebase SDK sample repo. If you check settings.gradle file in analytics folder you see that those modules are outside of it, in folder called internal

```
include ':internal:lintchecks'
project(':internal:lintchecks').projectDir = file('../internal/lintchecks')
include ':internal:lint'
project(':internal:lint').projectDir = file('../internal/lint')
include ':internal:chooser'
project(':internal:chooser').projectDir = file('../internal/chooser')
```

So either import entire sample folder with all other "projects" or just copy **internal** folder to your android studio project and change path of modules. settings.gradle will then look like this

```
include ':app'

// Required so that gradle can resolve these dependencies even when
// building only a single project.
include ':internal:lintchecks'
project(':internal:lintchecks').projectDir = file('internal/lintchecks')
include ':internal:lint'
project(':internal:lint').projectDir = file('internal/lint')
include ':internal:chooser'
project(':internal:chooser').projectDir = file('internal/chooser')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the real solution for this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check one space so it's also create a error

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:3.0.2'
```

Check it

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Yes it is actually a pasting typo error :/ I don't have the spaces in my real build.gradle, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
repositories {
        google()
        ...
```

In your root `Build.gradle` and update your `gradle` and google services to:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        ...
```

And replace the link in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Then try to rebuild-clean your project.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Thanks, I checked all these points and I still have the dependencies issues

Comment: `Could not resolve project :internal:lintchecks` It's coming from other included libraries-project (`internal:lintchecks`) in your case. That would be great to see that library's-project's dependencies.

Comment: I added a screenshot in the question, you can check. It seems that these library's projects dependencies don"t contain anything. Tell me if you need other screenshots I can take it

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now. Apply the suggestion first. Use latest version for the Firebase. `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4` then take an screenshot from `internal:lincheck`'s `build.gradle` since the error is coming from there. Perhaps a repository missed or something which needs to be checked.